# Is it possible to have multiple Aggregators in JUnit5 to start from different Indexes?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Is it possible to use Aggregators to aggregate multiple objects, each starting with the first index not used by previous Aggregations?

In the example that would be `true, true` for the first parameter and `true, false` for the second, but they both use `true, true`.

I tried using `context.getIndex()` but that only works when I know the length of previous Aggregators.

```
public class Test {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({ "true, true, true, false" })
    void test(@AggregateWith(And.class) boolean first,
            @AggregateWith(And.class) boolean second) {
        assertThat(first).isTrue();
        assertThat(second).isFalse();
    }

}

class And implements ArgumentsAggregator {

    @Override
    public Object aggregateArguments(ArgumentsAccessor arguments,
            ParameterContext context) throws ArgumentsAggregationException {

        return arguments.getBoolean(0) && arguments.getBoolean(1);
    }

}
```